# Solving 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve

$$ g'+\lambda^2 g = 0  $$

I am guessing I can use the P(x) and Q(x) method, but I cannot seem to get it to workout.

Obviously:

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int{p(x)}dx}  $$ where $$p(x)=\lambda^2$$

From there I say:

$$e^{\lambda^2}g'=0$$

This does not seem to work.

Any help?

Comment: is $\lambda$ a constant or a function?

Comment: it is a constant

Comment: So its a separable variable DE

Comment: oh hahahaha i got it thanks

Comment: forgot i could just separate, wow

Comment: why doesn't  $g = Ce^{-\lambda^2 t}, \text{ where $C$ is constant. }$

Comment: You actually almost got it, just made one small mistake. Well, two...
$$
\mu(x) = e^{\int pdx} = e^{\int \lambda^2 dx} = e^{\lambda^2 x}
$$
so
$$
\left( e^{\lambda^2 x} g \right)' = 0 \implies e^{\lambda^2 x} g = C \implies g = C e^{-\lambda^2 x}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, we have 
$$g'+\lambda^2g=0$$ $$\frac{dg}{dx}=-\lambda^2g$$
$$\frac{dg}{g}=-\lambda^2 dx$$

$$\int \frac{dg}{g}=-\lambda^2\int dx$$
$$\ln g=-\lambda^2 x+\ln C$$ $$\lambda^2 x=\ln \frac{C}{g}$$ $$\frac{C}{g}=e^{\lambda^2 x}$$ $$g=Ce^{-\lambda^2 x}$$
Hence, the solution is given as 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{g=Ce^{-\lambda^2 x}}}$$
Where, C is constant of integration

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$$
g'+{\lambda}^{2}g = 0
$$

so:

$$
g'=-{\lambda}^{2}g\\
\frac{dg}{dx} = -{\lambda}^{2}g\\
\frac{dg}{g} = -{\lambda}^{2}dx\\
$$

Now integrate:

$$
\int \frac{dg}{g} = -\int {\lambda}^{2}dx\\
ln(g)-ln(g_0) = -{\lambda}^{2}x\\
ln(\frac{g}{g_0}) = -{\lambda}^{2}x\\
\frac{g}{g_0} = {e}^{-{\lambda}^{2}x}\\
g = g_0{e}^{-{\lambda}^{2}x}
$$

You would calculate $g_0$ from initial conditions.

Have a nice day ;)